# Android DFM Dynamic FeatureModule Resources NotFoundException

Tags: android, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-delivery

In our app we start using Dynamic Feature Module (DFM) for big resources. We move most of drawables to DFM and load them if needed.

For loading drawable using a Provider and application context (as in documentation), and it works only if dfm loaded

```
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext, DFM.getDrawableResID(m_drawableName));
```

DFM.getDrawableResID(m_drawableName) - return resource ID (DrawableRes) from module

in Application class overrided attachBaseContext

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context ) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        SplitCompat.install(this)
    }
```

in MainActivity of main module attachBaseContext overrided too

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase)
        SplitCompat.installActivity(this)
    }
```

Downloading module works and after downloading there is a drawables in a list.
But after app restart always -

```
No package ID 7e found for ID 0x7e010219
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Resource ID #0x7e0101e4
```

Module installed and file list get from module without problems...

Answer (score 0):

resolved:

We can use application context only after install in that "session".
After restarting app and SplitCompat.install() (in application & activity) all DFM resources available by activity context only